# Count Distinct Window Function with Groupby

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

I have a table that contains a user's name, market, and purchase_id. I'm trying to use a window function in SnowSql without a subquery to count the distinct number of purchases a user bought as well as the total number of unique purchases for the market.

Initial Table

| User | Market | Purchase_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | NYC | 1 |
| John Smith | NYC | 2 |
| Bob Miller | NYC | 2 |
| Bob Miller | NYC | 4 |
| Tim Wilson | NYC | 3 |

The desired result would look like this:

| User | Purchases | Unique Market Purchases |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | 2 | 4 |
| Bob Miller | 2 | 4 |
| Tim Wilson | 1 | 4 |

The query I've been attempting without a subquery looks like the below but receives an error with the groupby.

```
SELECT 
  user,
  COUNT(DISTINCT purchase_id),
  COUNT(DISTINCT purchase_id) OVER (partition by market)
FROM table
GROUP BY 1
```

Appreciate any assistance with this. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you `group by user`, instead of by 1?

Comment: @JaimeDrq it is the same 1 stands for first column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work , you could wrangle to get into the format you're after but it produces the answer without subquery.

Uses the awesome [GROUPING SETS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/group-by-grouping-sets.html) which allows multiple group-by clauses in a single statement - the exact error you were hitting :-).

Awesome question!

```
  SELECT 
      COUNT(DISTINCT PURCHASE_ID)  
    , USER_NAME
    , MARKET
 FROM 
    CTE
  GROUP BY 
    GROUPING SETS (USER_NAME, MARKET);
```

[image]

Copy|Paste|Run

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT 'JOHN SMITH' USER_NAME, 'NYC' MARKET,   1 
PURCHASE_ID
UNION SELECT 'JOHN SMITH' USER_NAME,    'NYC' MARKET,   2 PURCHASE_ID
UNION SELECT 'BOB MILLER' USER_NAME,    'NYC' MARKET,   2 PURCHASE_ID
UNION SELECT 'BOB MILLER' USER_NAME,    'NYC' MARKET,   4 PURCHASE_ID
UNION SELECT 'TIM WILSON' USER_NAME,    'NYC' MARKET,   3 PURCHASE_ID) 

SELECT 
      COUNT(DISTINCT PURCHASE_ID)  
    , USER_NAME
    , MARKET
FROM 
    CTE
GROUP BY 
    GROUPING SETS (USER_NAME, MARKET);
```

Comment: There is no MySQL tag … it’s snowflake tagged. Why does a snowflake question need to be compatible with MySQL??

Comment: sorry it was retagged

Comment: You're welcome ... glad you took the time to read it through all the other answers !

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this simply as an aggregation.  But you can get the answer like this:

```
SELECT user,
       SUM( (seqnum = 1)::INT ) as purchases,
       SUM(SUM( (seqnum = 1)::INT )) OVER (PARTITION BY market) as market_purchases
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY purchase_id ORDER BY purchase_id) as seqnum
      FROM table t
     ) t
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: Kind of goes against the requirement: "I'm trying to use a window function in SnowSql without a subquery"

Comment: as you can see there is no such possibility with window functions

Answer (score 1):

`DISTTNCT` in a window function is not allowed, so you need to use the subquery

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1
>     (`User` varchar(10), `Market` varchar(3), `Purchase_ID` int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO table1
>     (`User`, `Market`, `Purchase_ID`)
> VALUES
>     ('John Smith', 'NYC', 1),
>     ('John Smith', 'NYC', 2),
>     ('Bob Miller', 'NYC', 2),
>     ('Bob Miller', 'NYC', 4),
>     ('Tim Wilson', 'NYC', 3)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>   user,
>   COUNT(DISTINCT purchase_id)
>   ,MAX((SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT purchase_id) FROM table1 WHERE `Market` = t1.`Market` )) bymarkte
> FROM table1 t1
> GROUP BY 1
> ```

> ```
> user       | COUNT(DISTINCT purchase_id) | bymarkte
> :--------- | --------------------------: | -------:
> Bob Miller |                           2 |        4
> John Smith |                           2 |        4
> Tim Wilson |                           1 |        4
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>   user,
>   COUNT(DISTINCT purchase_id)
>   ,MAX(countr) bymarkte
> FROM table1 t1
> INNER JOIN (SELECT `Market`,COUNT(DISTINCT purchase_id) countr FROM table1 GROUP BY  `Market` ) ta ON t1.`Market` = ta.`Market`
>
> GROUP BY 1
> ```
>
> ```
> user       | COUNT(DISTINCT purchase_id) | bymarkte
> :--------- | --------------------------: | -------:
> Bob Miller |                           2 |        4
> John Smith |                           2 |        4
> Tim Wilson |                           1 |        4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=94cc0e18e929c1310b52f99344f2dbde)*

Comment: Does MySQL have group roll ups ? That’s another way of solving this question

Comment: yes mysql has those https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: but i can't see how you will manage the distinct

Comment: Roll ups solve without sub query as well … just needs more wrangling to get into his desired output.

Comment: yes but the urser wanzs a "simple" solution with window functions and i don't see that happen any time soon

Comment: see the comments under Gorgons answer